# Problema al redireccionar segun role - Laravel y Spatie

Tags: laravel

Hola a todos buenas tardes, resulta que estoy trabajando con Laravel y el paquete Spatie para roles y permisos, todo bien hasta que me encuentro con la siguiente problematica: necesito que al realziar el login me rediriga a una vista especifica segun el role del usuario que se ha logueado.

Tengo 4 roles: Usuario, Ejecutor, Supervisor, Analista

En el controlador HomeController tengo este codigo:

```
 public function index()
    {

        $user= auth()->user()->id;
   
       $userLogueado = User::find($user);


       $rol= $userLogueado->roles->first();

       //dd($userLogueado);

        if($rol = "Ejecutor"){
            return view('Vistas_Perfiles.ejecutor');
        }
        elseif($rol = "Ejecutor"){
            return view('Vistas_Perfiles.ejecutor');
        }

    }
```

Hasta ahora solamente me funciona con el primer if, cuando agrego otro if para otro rol no funciona (me redirige al home por defecto)

Porque sera que solo me toma un if? habra alguna forma mejor de hacerlo?
Saludos a todos

Comment: si le agrego === queda en blanco la pantalla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESUELTO: Finalmente con $rol->admin  == 'admin' {

}

Saludos a todos

Comment: En lugar de escribir "resuelto", [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Recuerda que el formato del sitio es de preguntas y respuestas, no de un foro :)